# Where is Websphere compiling Jasper jrxmls

Tags: compilation, jasper-reports, websphere-7

I know that when you deploy an ear/war with jrxmls, they are compiled into .jasper file automatically.

I am working with Websphere 7.0 and the issue is that i cant see the jasper files after compilation, i see in SystemOut.log that they are being compiled but I dont see any jaspers being generated.

[1/22/13 10:20:16:241 AST] 00000031 jasperReportMu I org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView loadReport Compiling Jasper Report loaded from ServletContext resource [/reports/xml/JSreport1.jrxml] 
[1/22/13 10:20:16:588 AST] 00000031 jasperReportMu I org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView loadReport Compiling Jasper Report loaded from ServletContext resource [/reports/xml/sreport2.jrxml] 
[1/22/13 10:20:16:826 AST] 00000031 jasperTextView I org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView loadReport Compiling Jasper Report loaded from ServletContext resource [/reports/xml/sreport4.jrxml]

Has some one seen this issue, as per logs I should have some .jasper files but I dont see any.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following Java system properties in the app server console:

`jasper.reports.compile.temp` to point to the directory where you want to see the compile results.

`jasper.reports.compile.keep.java.file` set to true so that the files are not deleted after the compile

Comment: where can i set these properties, Are these Custom Properties, both of them?. I have not seen these properties before in app server console before.

Comment: Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name, and then, under Server Infrastructure, click Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine > Custom properties (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fxrun_jvm.html)

Comment: Thanks Akber, I did that and i started gettinmg .java files instead of .jasper files. What do i need to do more for this. I have never seen ;java files for jrxmls

Comment: It has been a while. It should be within nested folders that correspond to the package name.  Take a look at the folders with the Java files or the `Websphere/Appserver/temp` folder.

Comment: i did get the Java files in the first try in the same folder, I am not able to get the .jasper files any where so my reports are failing cos of that.